# Какой принцип работы стандартной библиотеки?

Tags: c++

Уважаемые пользователи, нужна помощь новичку в С++. Возможно я ставлю вопросы некорректно, в свете моей "зелёности" в этом деле, но тягу к знаниям не отнять. Долго я искал в интернете какой принцип работы у стандартной библиотеки, к примеру у той же iostream, но так и не нашел(может плохо искал). Можете пожалуйста объяснить как она устроена изнутри и какие процессы обеспечивают работоспособность? Либо где можно посмотреть ее реализацию.

С ув.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ничего там нет необычного. Но сможете ли разобраться, посмотрев внутрь - я не знаю. Поэтому, надо делать план по другому.

Для начала стоит почитать базового по плюсам, к примеру, [Программирование. Принципы и практика с использованием C++ | Страуструп Бьерн](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/140985739/). В этой книге, к примеру, рассказывается как сделать свой вектор с аллокатором. Без этого смотреть стандартную библиотеку даже нет смысла.

Потом книгу по стандартной библиотеке [Стандартная библиотека C++: справочное руководство](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1837-6.html)

А потом открыть собственно код библиотеки и посмотреть. Например от [gcc](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3) или [Майкрософт](https://github.com/microsoft/STL). Но там не все так очевидно.